# Cannot focus on input in ios7 safari with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have a very simple example here

http://jsbin.com/sekuxuyi/1

(edit)
http://jsbin.com/sekuxuyi/1/edit

All this does is show an input, when the page loads jquery finds the dom element and calls `focus()` on it. On desktop this works fine but in the iOS simulator I cannot get this to work. I would expect the keyboard to show and the element to be focused. Is there anything specific for iOS that I am missing out on to get this to function?

Comment: Doing some more research, is seems that I can focus on an input only after an user interaction event: http://jsbin.com/fexoyuxa/2

Comment: I don't think it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714084/autofocus-with-keyboard-in-an-ipad-html5-site